# How to add a scrollable view within a collectionView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I need to add a scrollview within a collectionViewCell. This is confusing me because there are essentially two ways of scrolling. You can either scroll from one collectionView cell to the next or within a collectionView Cell itself, to get more info from inside the cell. I have attached a picture of what my collectionView cell looks like right now. I would like for the scrollview to scroll within the gray view. How should I set this up in my interface builder?

Thanks so much!

I have also attached the current heirarchy for my scrollview *Scrolling functionality is not working at the moment.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Whats the problem here? You simply have to make your own custom cell and add a UIScrollView to it... Or if the cell contains a collection view, do just that.

Comment: How should the hierarchy look? Should my scrollview go under the gray view?

Comment: I have tried simply adding in the scrollview from the interface builder, but it does not appear to be scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You have a custom collection view cell already just add a scrollView and then anything you want to display in the cell. So your hierarchy would be something like this :
Custom-Cell: ContentView > UIScrollView > then anything you want to add in the view.